# Как сделать чтобы объект двигался с постоянной скоростью к определенной точке?

Tags: unity3d

Есть две точки А и Б. Объект должен перемещаться от одной точки к другой с постоянной скоростью. Есть возможность во время перемещения управлять персонажем влево или вправо. Дорога, по которой перемещается объект, не прямая, а извилистая. Вопрос - как это можно реализовать?
P.S. Перемещение влево и вправо и движение по прямой я знаю как делать, а вот так, чтобы он двигался по извилистой дороге плавно, не могу понять движение. Похоже как в играх типа CubeSurfer, StackColors?

Comment: поизучай NavMesh

Comment: google -> "unity spline movement"

Comment: Спасибо Andrew  помогло

Comment: вопрос решен _______________________________________